# jq - check for subkey without filtering

Tags: json, key, jq

I would like to check for the presence of a subkey (or for its type) in a JSON file using jq without filtering the data. I need this to obtain a list of all entities from the following JSON file, with the first pair of coordinates if more than one pair is available. The problem is the partly nested structure: The "location" object is only available for some entries, and the "coordinates" element is an array only if multiple locations are available.

```
{"records":[
{
    "id": 1,
    "location": {
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 42,
            "lon": -71
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "location": {
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "lat": 40,
                "lon": -73
            },
            {
                "lat": 39,
                "lon": -75
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "location": null
}]}
```

So I tried the "has" function, which does not seem to work for subkeys. I imagined something like this:

```
cat file.json | jq '.records[] | if has("location.coordinates") then [do something] else [do something else] end'
```

Is there any way to check for subkeys? As I need to maintain all entries in the dataset, filtering via "select" etc. does not seem to be an option.

To clarify my question: I hoped to get a JSON output similar to this (but I would be happy to handle other formats):

```
{"records":[
{"id": 1, "lat", xx, "lon": xx}
{"id": 2, "lat", yy, "lon": yy}
{"id": 3, "lat", null, "lon": null}
]}
```

Comment: What output do you expect for the sample input?

Comment: So id 3 should not be in the output?

Comment: As stated (though probably not adequately highlighted) in the first paragraph: the first available coordinate pair should be chosen. To be clear: ALL ids should be in the output. If they do not have coordinates, the coordinate fields should be empty.

Comment: Yea but id=3 has no location, so what do you expect with that?

Comment: @0stone0 : All ids should be in the result. I was just editing my last comment when I got your question.

Comment: Ahh I did not see that. Changes my answer. Maybe you could edit your expected result to the actual result with the empty id=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [error suppression operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression/OptionalOperator:?) `?` in combination with the [alterative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) `//` to fall back to another case if the previous one fails:

```bash
.records[] |= (.location.coordinates | .[0]? // .) as {$lat,$lon} | {id,$lat,$lon}
```

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lat": 42,
      "lon": -71
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "lat": 40,
      "lon": -73
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "lat": null,
      "lon": null
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A0NSbuco7Fh)

Answer (score 0):

Instead off `has`, you can use a `select` with an `|=` opertator:

```
.records |= map(.id as $id | (.location.coordinates | (if type == "array" then .[0] else . end) as $q | ({ $id, lat: null, lon: null } + $q) ))
```

This generates:

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lat": 42,
      "lon": -71
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "lat": 40,
      "lon": -73
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "lat": null,
      "lon": null
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can try in this [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HquJhGqPZKo).

---

So, the above explained:

1. Loop over `records` and update them 
   `.records |= map()`
2. Save the id
   `.id as $id`
3. Continue on the coordinates
   `.location.coordinates |`
4. Check for an array, if so, get the fist object, otherwise, just keep it, save as `$q`
   `(if type == "array" then .[0] else . end) as $q`
5. Create the final object, start with an object with just the `id` and `lat` and `lon` set to `null`, then we combine `$q` to get the actual values from the coordinates
   `({ $id, lat: null, lon: null } + $q)`

---

This could most probably be simplified, so waiting for another answer that has the same idea, but more optimised.

Comment: Thank you very much @0stone0 . With your helpful code example and the explanation I learned about "carrying forward" variables for later use. As I did not need to filter the results, I could further simplify the code to `cat file.json | jq '.records[] | .id as $id | .location.coordinates | if type == "array" then .[0] else . end | {id: $id, lat: .lat, lon: .lon}'` (omitting the "records" bracket around everything).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alternative operator `//` :

```
jq '.records[] |= {id}+((.location.coordinates? |
                         if type == "array" then .[0] else . end
                        ) // {}
                       )' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.6, `jq` has introduced the [destructuring alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DestructuringAlternativeOperator:?//) `?//` which

> provides a concise mechanism for destructuring an input that can take one of several forms

That way, you could define one case with an array, and another one without, using the same variable names. As "unmatched" variables (in the alternative that succeeded) are set to `null`, there's no need to explicitly deal with the third case.

```bash
jq '.records |= map(
  .location as {coordinates: [{$lat, $lon}]} ?// {coordinates: {$lat, $lon}}
  | {id, $lat, $lon}
)'
```

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "lat": 42,
      "lon": -71
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "lat": 40,
      "lon": -73
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "lat": null,
      "lon": null
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ocISRTlxWXf)